# Why does running docker with ProcessBuilder cause a hang?

Tags: java, process, docker

I'm trying to run a command in a docker container using Java's [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html). However, it hangs when waiting for exit code. Why is that?

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(Arrays.asList("/usr/bin/docker", "run", "base", "echo", "hello"));

Process process = processBuilder.start();

// ... Spin off another thread to collect stdout and stderr

int exitCode = process.waitFor(); // <-- HANG
```

I can see that the process spits out the correct results to stdout. It just never returns an exit code.

Comment: One possible problem: you don't appear to be gobbling the process's InputStream and the ErrorStreams. You could be overrunning the buffers available for these streams. For more on this, please read [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html). Read it all as it's all important.

Comment: @Hovercraft, I start up another thread to gobble those. I tested my code running the `echo hello` command without docker, and it works.

Comment: What happens when you run `/usr/bin/docker run base echo hello` from the command line?  Does it exit?

Comment: @StephenC, yes, it exits with a 0 exit code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why use the `CLI` which is just a wrapper around the [API](http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/api/docker_remote_api/)? Better to use it directly from [java](https://github.com/kpelykh/docker-java).